# Changing text for check payment method on magento check out page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, php-5.4

I'm new to magento so please remember when responding. What I want to do is change the text on the magento check option. I had the ability to change the title to "wire transfer" but would like to change the text that says "make check payable to" and "send check to".

Please let me know if this is possible and where I would find this file. Thank you for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by enabling the translation mode in magento.
Connect to the admin

Go in `System-> Configuration ->Advanced -> developper -> Translated Inline -> Front End switch` to `yes`

You should see on the front end some red box around every texts, click on the one you need to translate, change it and then re-stwitch to off the translated inline mod when you are done.

Don't forget to disable the cache before doing that.

Comment: It made the change in the magento back end, does not apply to front end.

Comment: When you change the translation on the front-end it only changed the backend translations ?

Comment: Yes only in magento not on front end. This is a new install with only template and 1 shipping table extension.

Comment: to go further and to see which files is concerned you would need to enable to template hint path file it will show you which files path are concerned.  More info http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints turnit on and then it should indicates you the path of the file you need to investigate.

Comment: Works in Magento 2 as well, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text for those by going to `your_web_root/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/checkmo.phtml`

The text that gets displayed on the frontend can be found here.
I would copy this file to your theme and then make the necessary text changes.

After you make the change clear your cache if it is enabled.